# Using for-loop, iterate through 2D array in order to pass those values into parameter

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, methods, parameters

I am opening a text file that looks like this:

```
1;Rani;Hockey;BMW;1 Series;2011;WAUGFAFR4CA952133;2003;
2;Ranice;Dodge;Hyundai;Sonata;2005;WAUMF78PX6A683500;2013;
```

(has 90 more lines similar to the above)

I have already split each words into a 2D array such that positions

```
[0][0] = 1
[0][1] = Rani
[0][2] = Hockey
[1][0] = 2
[1][1] = Ranice
[1][7] = 2013
```

I setup a for-loop to iterate through my 2D Array where (eventually) each index will be passed as a parameter to a constructor that I have. During the loop I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException:
For input string: "2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Test4.main(Test4.java:53)
```

Below are my code for my CarData class:

```
public CarData() {}

public CarData(int i, String fn, String ln, String cMake, String cMdl, 
                   int cYear, String vin, int p)
{
    this.customerID = i;
    this.ownerFirstName = fn;
    this.ownerLastName = ln;
    this.carMake = cMake;
    this.carModel = cMdl;
    this.carYear = cYear;
    this.carVin = vin;
    this.yearCarPurchased = p;
}
```

---

```
public class CarDataDriver {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    final int col = 8;
    final int row = 100;
    int id = 0;
    String fn = null;
    String ln = null;
    String cMake = null;
    String cMdl = null;
    int cYear = 0;
    String vin = null;
    int p = 0;
    CarData [] data = new CarData[row];
    // Open file
    File file = new File("CarData.txt");

    // Use scanner to scan new File
    Scanner scanner;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);

        // useDelimiter to separate String 
        String text = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        // Use split method to split String
        String [] array = text.split(";");

        String[][] array2D = new String[row][col];

        //iterate through array to create 2D array
        for (int i = 0, k=0; i < array2D.length; i++)
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                array2D[i][j] = array[k++];
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0, k=0; i < array2D.length; i++) 
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if(j==0){
                    id = Integer.parseInt(array2D[i][j]); //first iteration where i = 0 runs fine, when i=1 and j=0 I get the error
                    continue;
                }
                if(j==1){
                    fn = array2D[i][j];
                    continue;
                }
                if(j==2)         {                   
                    ln = array2D[i][j];
                    continue;
                }
                if(j==3){
                    cMake = array2D[i][j];
                    continue;
                }
                if(j==4){
                    cMdl = array2D[i][j];
                    continue;
                }
                if(j==5){
                    cYear = Integer.parseInt(array2D[i][j]);
                    continue;
                }
                if(j==6){
                    vin = array2D[i][j];
                    continue;
                }
                if(j==7){
                    p = Integer.parseInt(array2D[i][j]);

                }
                data[k] = new CarData(id, fn, ln, cMake, cMdl, cYear, vin, p);
                k++;
            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your looping alone is fine - what is causing an error is an invalid character (a whitespace) parsed together with proper integer. You may simply remove all whitespaces from your string with:

```
array2D[i][j].replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

(note, that this not modifies a string in array, but returns new one with removed spaces)

Where strange `"\\s+"` string just means "any space character" (it's so called regular expression, but you don't need to understand it fully for now)

However, note, that you have some more issues in your code, for example absolutely unnecessary inner loop with so numerous `if`s, where every of them would execute just once - instead of this you can simply access array2D[i][1], array2D[i][2] and so on. Also keeping additional index k and incrementing it by hand seems to be redundant.

Anyway, keep coding and good luck!

P.S. Using `BufferedReader` and its `readLine()` seems to be a much better (and simpler!) way to read a file. Take a glimpse on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: When I try that i get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
 at Test4.main(Test4.java:47)